# What experimental grenades and ammo types are available?

Tags: xcom-2

I can't seem to find a list of the available experimental grenades and ammo types that can be developed in the Proving Grounds facility, as well as their effects.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 5 types of Experimental Ammo, and 3 types of Experimental grenades.

### Ammo

As a side note, Ammo applies to Sharpshooter pistol shots.

- **Armor Piercing** - Bypasses an enemy's armor. No bonuses against enemies without armor.
- **Dragon Rounds** - Passive bonus damage and a chance to light targets on fire. (Enemies immune to fire can't be lit on fire, but still take the bonus damage)
- **Talon Rounds** - [Reaper Rounds'](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Reaper_Rounds_%28EU2012%29) big brother! +20% passive crit, and an extra +1 damage on critical hits. No extra range penalties like its predecessor.
- **Tracer Rounds** - +10 Aim while equipped.
- **Venom Rounds** - Passive bonus damage and a chance to poison the target. (Enemies immune to poison, like Chyrssalids, still take the bonus damage)

### Grenades

- **Acid Grenade / Bomb** - Shreds more armor than a frag grenade, applies Acid to those hit, and leaves acid terrain tiles on the map for a few turns.
- **Gas Grenade / Bomb** - Larger area grenade that deals damage and poisons enemies hit.
- **Incendiary Grenade / Bomb** - High damage and sets enemies on fire.

And, though you didn't ask for it, why not --

### Heavy Weapons

Heavy weapons are tiered. The "Heavy Weapons" become available once you unlock the E.X.O. suit, and the "Powered Weapons" become available once you unlok the W.A.R. suit.

#### Heavy Weapons

- **Rocket Launcher** - Unlocked by default. Deals explosion damage in an area & shreds armor.
- **Flamethrower** - Cone of flame to deal damage and ignite enemies.
- **Shredder Gun** - Cone of bullets to shred armor and cover.
- **Blaster Launcher** - Powered Weapon. Upgraded Rocket Launcher.
- **Hellfire Projector** - Powered Weapon. Upgraded Flamethrower.
- **Shredstorm Cannon** - Powered Weapon. Upgraded Shredder Gun.
- **Plasma Blaster** - Powerd Weapon. Linear area damage.

Here's an [imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyR2c.jpg) assembled by SYLOH with the in-game descriptions.

Comment: Ah. So I developed experimental grenade and got an acid grenade - I assumed that experimental grenade = gas grenade. Does that mean each time I develop it I'll get a different grenade or will it just choose one randomly (so I might get another acid)?

Comment: It's random - you might get another acid, you might get the gas you're looking for.

Comment: Cool. Cheers. Not sure what I think of that. I'm surprised that once you've developed one you don't get the option to choose that specific one. Seems strange that if you've got an acid already that you can't just say "do the same thing again, I want more of those".

Comment: @Chris I agree. There'll probably be a mod for it eventually, though!

Comment: Does the shredder gun actually shred armor?  I just used one on an armored enemy, and they still had all their armor.

Comment: @Keen I can verify that both the Shredder Gun and the Shredstorm Cannon shred armor. Possibly you missed / some other shenanigans?