# What experimental armors can you discover in the Proving Grounds?

Tags: xcom-2

Along the lines of [What experimental grenades and ammo types are available?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254402/90128), what are the different kinds of experimental armor that you can discover in the Proving Grounds?

I don't mean the light and heavy tier 2 and tier 3 armors, i.e. Spider, EXO, Wraith, and WAR suits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same person cited in that answer for the images made [another album with the experimental armors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISKYD.jpg). There are only 3.

**Stasis Vest** - +2 HP & will regen 2 health every turn, up to a maximum of 8 health regenerated per mission.

**Plated Vest** - +2 HP & and Armor Pip

**Hazmat Vest** - +2 HP & Fire / Acid / Poison Immunity (Potentially bugged)

Comment: Only 3? That's a little disappointing. I hope they make new armors in an expansion.

Comment: Why is the Hazmat vest possibly bugged?

Comment: @DarthPizza I haven't verified that it works (or doesn't!), but there were folks on reddit talking about the immunity not working. YMMV

Comment: I've noticed even with other sources of immunity that it seems buggy, or just weird. I had a hacking bonus for "immunity to the next two attacks" on a soldier, and she still got knocked out by a stun lancer. She took no damage from the attack, so maybe it's just poorly worded/coded.